# c++ compiler optimized out my bool check function

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, compiler-optimization, clang++

I found some wired results when I am doing JNI development.

Here is my test code:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#define JNI_FALSE   0
#define JNI_TRUE    1

typedef uint8_t jboolean;

inline jboolean bool2jboolean( bool b ) { return b ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE; }

void test(bool *b) {

    volatile jboolean t = bool2jboolean(*b);

    std::cout << "t as int: " << (int)t << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t as bool : " << (bool)t << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t as jboolean(char) : " << t << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    int a = 105;
    test((bool*)&a);
    return 0;
}
```

-O0 works fine, but if I turn on -O3, seems bool2jboolean somehow got optimized out by the compiler:

```
$ clang++ -O0 test.cpp
$ ./a.out 
t as int: 1
t as bool : 1
t as jboolean(char) : 

$ clang++ -O3 test.cpp
$ ./a.out         
t as int: 105
t as bool : 1
t as jboolean(char) : i
```

I am not sure what is going on here.

Is the compiler assuming a bool will always be 0 or 1 ?

(So bool2jboolean become a meaningless function ?)

Tested on my mac:

```
$ clang++ -v
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

EDIT:
We can't ensure *b is pointing to a "normalized" bool (for example, an uninitialized bool with random value underlying), that is also the reason we introduced bool2jboolean, hope it can "check" the bool and return a validate jboolean. (Otherwise, JNI runtime will throw if t is not 0 nor 1.)

But seems bool2jboolean is completely failed to do that.

How can we check an uninitialized bool ? (bitwise op is the only way left ??)

Comment: in C++ trying to access an uninitialized variable in any way (other than to initialize it) is Undefined Behavior. There are a very few exceptions to this, but none apply to your case.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation

Comment: @M.M
Thank you! I thought a bool is true if the underlying value is not zero, but I think I was wrong, a legitimate bool need to be 0 or 1 in value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You intentionally lied to the compiler, telling it that the memory for `a` was a legal `bool`, even though C++ specifically says a `bool` can only be `true` or `false`. The compiler under high optimization realized that `true` was `1` and `false` was `0`, matching the `JNI_TRUE` and `JNI_FALSE` respectively, so it could just copy the value of the `bool` directly instead of making a conditional choice. Since `bool` "can't" be anything else, this was a safe optimization. You made it unsafe by lying to the compiler.

If you'd simply done:

```
int main() {
    int a = 105;
    bool b = a;
    test(&b);
    return 0;
}
```

it would have worked, as assignment to `bool` normalizes to `true` (for non-zero values) and `false` (for zero values), without *assuming* the value is already `true` or `false`. By contrast, your cast changed how memory was interpreted without that normalization (you asserted the memory pointed to was *already* in normal form).

Comment: I have edited my question, can you give it a look again? Thanks!

Comment: @zjysdhr: The edit doesn't change things. The solution to avoiding undefined behavior is to not engage in undefined behavior. Reading from an uninitialized `bool` is undefined, and thinking you *need* to do so indicates you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). If you have a non-bool, that you want to normalize to `true` or `false`, assign it to a `bool`. If you just want to normalize an arbitrary integer thing to `1` or `0`, you can just test it (no need to convert to `bool` first), e.g. `anyinteger ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE`, but it should still be initialized.

Comment: Your edit does not change the problem.  You CANNOT write a program to handle uninitialized variables.  The C++ standard makes that "undefined behavior", and the compiler is allowed to do anything in response.

Comment: Thank you guys! Well, now at least I can tell why bool2jboolean is not working as we expected. Same kind of interface is provided to the end users, sometime we just can't relay on users to do the "proper initialization" before calling our API. We just want to keep our program from crashing.

Comment: @zjysdhr: If your API to accepts `bool*`, and the users of your API are not providing legal `bool*`s, that's on them, not you. You can't protect against users that willfully misuse an API, or write their own code with undefined behavior in it (and what little you could try to do would involve slowing things down for everyone using it correctly to make wild guesses at how the API might be misused, and likely still missing other types of misuse; if you require a non-NULL pointer for instance, you can check for `NULL`, but any other invalid pointer will just crash on use).